# Maven Plugin Logger Compatibility

Tags: java, maven-2, logging, log4j, mojo

I am writing a Maven plugin (Mojo) that imports a Jar library used by other projects. At least one of the classes in that library use Apache Log4j for logging, but Log4j is not going to be properly configured by the logger that Maven provides to the Mojo.

Is there any simple way to bridge between these? Unfortunately, `org.apache.log4j.Logger` and `org.apache.maven.logging.Log` do not share a common superinterface or superclass, so I can't simply have a `setLog()` type function. Any suggestions would be welcome; currently I am planning to either just ignore it, or write a bridge class that can use either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to write a bridge class, look at SLF4J sources: http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html#log4j-over-slf4j 
They are doing something quite similar in their log4j bridge.

Comment: Not exactly what I was hoping for, but thanks for the info. If nobody else gives a better answer within about a week, I'll accept this one.

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem and solved writing a simple bridge across Maven Logger and Log4j:

```
import org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton;
import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.logging.Log;

public class MavenLoggerLog4jBridge extends AppenderSkeleton {
    private Log logger;

    public MavenLoggerLog4jBridge(Log logger) {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    protected void append(LoggingEvent event) {
        int level = event.getLevel().toInt();
        String msg = event.getMessage().toString();
        if (level == Level.DEBUG_INT || level == Level.TRACE_INT) {
            this.logger.debug(msg);
        } else if (level == Level.INFO_INT) {
            this.logger.info(msg);
        } else if (level == Level.WARN_INT) {
            this.logger.warn(msg);
        } else if (level == Level.ERROR_INT || level == Level.FATAL_INT) {
            this.logger.error(msg);
        }
    }

    public void close() {
    }

    public boolean requiresLayout() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And in my Mojo, I used the *BasicConfigurator* class of Log4j API, with an instance of this bridge:

```
public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException {
    org.apache.maven.plugin.logging.Log mavenLogger = getLog();
    BasicConfigurator.configure(new MavenLoggerLog4jBridge(mavenLogger));
}
```

I don't know if Maven infrastructure already have this bridge, I haven't tried to search something more "maven-like", but this solution worked fine.

Comment: Thanks a million!  Your bridge and solution saved me a lot of trouble.