# How to add maven build output to plugin classloader?

Tags: java, maven, plugins, classloader, maven-plugin

I'm running into a problem with an AntTask run within the `maven-antrun-plugin`.  Unfortunately, the AntTask uses the plugin classloader to locate a file from the project, but when run from within a plugin, the build output is not included in the plugin's classpath.

From the [Guide to Maven Classloading](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-maven-classloading.html):

> Please note that the plugin classloader does neither contain the
>   dependencies of the current project nor its build output.
>
> ...
>
> Plugins are free to create further classloaders on their discretion.
>   For example, a plugin might want to create a classloader that combines
>   the plugin class path and the project class path.

Can anyone point me in right direction how to create my own version of the maven-antrun-plugin in which I can create my own classloader that combines the plugin class path and the project class path?  I need to update the classloader such that when a class executed by my custom antrun-plugin calls:

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource()
```

the classloader will search the build output folder as well.

Comment: What are you trying to do? And why using maven-antrun-plugin?

Comment: @khmarbaise I'm trying to convert a legacy ant project to maven. Unfortunately part of the ant build uses a defunct Kodo Ant task for JDO enhancing of entities for which I have found no maven equivalent. So I am just trying to call the ant task via the maven-Antrim-plugin. But as I explained, the task uses the class loader to locate a properties file in the class path. But since the plugin class loader does not include the build sources/output, it fails to find it and the task fails. Modifying the ant task isn't really an option so I was looking to modify the class path of the plugin loader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After several hours trying to work my way around this issue with configuration, I bit the bullet and simply wrote my own plugin that extends the AntRun plugin.  This was done using Maven 3.2.5:

```
@Mojo( name = "run", threadSafe = true, requiresDependencyResolution = ResolutionScope.TEST )
public class CustomAntMojo
    extends AntRunMojo
{

    @Component
    private PluginDescriptor pluginDescriptor;

    public void execute()
        throws MojoExecutionException
    {
        File buildDirectory = new File( getMavenProject().getBuild().getOutputDirectory() );

        // add the build directory to the classpath for the classloader
        try {
            ClassRealm realm = pluginDescriptor.getClassRealm();
            realm.addURL(buildDirectory.toURI().toURL());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        // configure the log4j logger to output the ant logs to the maven log
        BasicConfigurator.configure( new MavenLoggerLog4jBridge(getLog()));
        super.execute();

    }
}
```

With the MavenLoggerLog4jBridge class being used to convert from my Ant task's Log4j output to maven logger (https://stackoverflow.com/a/6948208/827480):

```
import org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton;
import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.logging.Log;
public class MavenLoggerLog4jBridge extends AppenderSkeleton {
    private Log logger;

    public MavenLoggerLog4jBridge(Log logger) {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    protected void append(LoggingEvent event) {
        int level = event.getLevel().toInt();
        String msg = event.getMessage().toString();
        if (level <= Level.DEBUG_INT ) {
            this.logger.debug(msg);
        } else if (level == Level.INFO_INT) {
            this.logger.info(msg);
        } else if (level == Level.WARN_INT) {
            this.logger.warn(msg);
        } else if (level == Level.ERROR_INT || level == Level.FATAL_INT) {
            this.logger.error(msg);
        }
    }

    public void close() {
    }

    public boolean requiresLayout() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Hopefully it might be of some use or assistance to someone in the future.